# mysql start ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password no) in OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, webserver, opensuse

running openSuse 12.1 . on a notebook...

well i configured apache 2 and mysql - (after starting it on the runlevel.

well - i did all i needed to do - but now i stuck....

after installing phpmyadmin . i tried to find the site ... i couldnt

then i tried to start the mysql via command line - which failed ... duhhhhhh!!?? What can i do now - what is wrong here

```
linux-wyee:/home/martin # mysql start 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
linux-wyee:/home/martin #
```

hmmm i have no glue - probably i have messed up some passwords . what do you think!
how can i make sure that all runs nice -and nothing - that means no pART OF the apache2, mysql and all that things
quits to work propperly

Comment: Error 1045 is detailed here: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should use **systemctl** to start the mysql server daemon

```
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

Also if you want to add the server to the suse standard runlevels you should use:

```
sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
```

Next up you must execute **mysql_secure_installation** as root.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

here you must follow the steps and enter the password for the root mysql user. note that this is **not** the root user of your linux box.

Now simply use the mysql client. Simply issue

```
mysql
```

^^And remember you are on suse. Something sugested like **rcscript  start** would not work because suse is using systemd now.

Comment: Hello and good day! Great to hear from you!! i will do all you adviced. i come back and report all my findings! Greeting

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql install is just complaining that you can't connect to the instance on mysql locally as root without using a password. If you forgot the password or don't know what it is, you can reset it as follows:

1. Kill the current mysql process running (do a ps -efc| more) or something and kill anything that says MySQL with `kill <process_id>`. A better alternative is to try and simply stop the process gracefully with `rcmysql stop`
2. Create a file (ideally in a directory that only root can read) called `init.txt` with the following text:

   > UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NewPassword') WHERE
   >   User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
3. Launch MySQL in safe mode and passing the init.txt file as parameter as so:

   ```
   mysqld_safe --init-file=mysql-init.txt &
   ```

Now you can kill MySQL once again and restart the service normally (I think Suse uses `rcmysql start`:

> rcmysql start

Connect to the server as you'd normarlly do with:

> mysql -u root@localhost -p

Enter the password you specified in the init.txt file and you should be good to go. DELETE the init.txt file!!!!

Comment: Hello and good day! i will do all you adviced. i come back and  report all my findings! Greetings

Comment: DO NOT USE "kill -9"! In worst case you can even destroy your database. Always use just "kill" and check if mySQL dæmon is died within a couple of seconds. If normal kill does not help then only in last resort use flag -9